# Can't display a value for a variable in cent OS

Tags: shell, centos

I created a script in cent OS as following :

```
vi sc2
set var1=hello
set var2=$LOGNAME
export
<Esc>
:wq!
```

When I want to display the value of var1 and var2 I get a blank value.

```
ls -l
chmod 700 sc2
./sc2
echo $var1
echo $var2
```

Could you please help me with the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

If this is `bash` then that's not how you set variables. You just assign to them `var1=hello`. And that `export` should have printed out some variables to you, did it?

If this is `csh`/`tcsh` then that correctly set the variables but I don't think `export` is valid.

Beyond those details you have another problem.

When you ran `./sc2` you started a *new* shell so the variables set in that shell (exported or not) are not visible by the parent shell (this is different then using `. sc2` which **would** set them in the main shell as there is no sub-shell in that case).